# Preferred PHP 7.0 repo for Drupal 8 + CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, php-7, drupal-8

I am installing D8 on a CentOS 7 system with PHP 7.0. (This will be a dedicated Drupal 8 system.)

A sysadmin co-worker recommended Remi's PHP 7.0 repo, which installs PHP into `/opt/remi/php70/root/bin` (instead of the familiar `/usr/bin`).

The final step in the installation is a bash script, which modifies your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

(It does not set DRUSH_PHP)

Does anyone have any experience with this repo? (Most of the builds I've worked on in the past have installed PHP into `/usr/bin` ). Any "gotchas" here?

Is there a more-preferred CentOS 7 repo to use?

Many thanks!

Comment: Other 3rd party repository are mostly pulling their sources from Fedora, while "remi" is upstream for Fedora (which means, things happens there, and then are pushed to Fedora, then pulled by others).

Answer (score 0):

In "remi" repo you have choice between single versions (installation in standard directory) and multiple versions (parallel installation in /opt).

In your case, single version seems simpler.

See the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.

To summarize:

- **php-cli** (in remi-php70 repo) provides /usr/bin/php
- **php70-php-cli** (SCL, in remi-safe repo) provides /opt/remi/php70/root/bin/php and allow multiple versions to be installed simultaneously.

Comment: I had not seen the wizard before -- it's very useful.

However, following the wizard's instructions for "single version", it (again) installed PHP into /opt/remi/php70/root/bin/php

Most of the builds I've worked on in the past have installed PHP into /usr/bin -- are there any Drupal 8 "gotchas" around placing PHP outside of /usr/bin?

(Alternatively, is there a config that will install this into /usr/bin ?)

Comment: No, Using single version, install /usr/bin/php